# Help identifying this Japanese font

Tags: typography

[image]

Love this retro style font, does anyone know what it is? Or anything similar? Thanks so much

Comment: Try likefont.com.  It can sometimes identify CJK fonts automatically. Failing that, they also have a forum where you can ask humans.